# Import specific partitions from a table into hadoop

Tags: oracle, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I am using sqoop to import data into hadoop. I am using below command to import a table into hadoop.

```
 sqoop import \
 --connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.16.XXX.XXX:15XX:TABS \
 --username user \
 --password pass \
 --table TABS.ADM_LOG0009 \
 --target-dir /hadoop/hptabs/recharge
```

Now I have another table named IVM_IMAGE, which is a partitioned table. I want to import only 3 partitions from Oracle to hadoop. Please help me to write command for this.

- Oracle table name: TABS.IVM_IMAGE
- Partitions: LESS20161101, LESS20161001, LESS20160901
- Partiton key: BILLDATE
- HIVE table name: hptabs.IVM_IMAGE

Table properties:

> PARTITIONED BY (BILLDATE TIMESTAMP) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS
>   TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION 'hdfs:/hadoop/hptabs/usage';

Comment: You mean **Hive table name** not **Hadoop table name**. Right?

Comment: Yes Hive table name.

Comment: [this](https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html#_match_hadoop_files_to_oracle_table_partitions) will help.

Comment: Thanks. it works at last.

Comment: Good to know..!  You can self-answer _(if you want)_ to help the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To import specific partitions i need to add "-Doraoop.import.partitions='"LESS20161101","LESS20161001","LESS20160901",'" to my sqoop command

```
sqoop import \
-Doraoop.disabled=false \
-Doraoop.import.partitions='"LESS20161101","LESS20161001","LESS20160901",' \
--connect jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.16.XXX.XXX:15XX:TABS \
--username user \
--password password \
--table TABS.IVM_IMAGE \
--target-dir /hadoop/hptabs/usage/ \
-m 1
```